# React - Handle jwt auth fail using await fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, fetch-api

I wrote an API that do some stuff, and I protect this using a `jwt` token. 
This is the function for check the validity (`checkAuth`):

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    req.userData = decoded;
    next();
  }
  catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Auth failed'
    });
  }
};
```

And I define the `route` of the `API` in this way:

```
router.post('/myAPI', checkAuth, MyAPIDefinition);
```

When I try to fetch the API, using an **expired** `jwt` I can't get the response of the `checkAuth`. This is my `API` call using `await fetch`:

```
const response = await fetch(`${API_URI_DEV}/myAPI`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({encod: { content: data }}),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'authorization': jwt
  }
});
```

The content of `response` is `undefined`.

Comment: is `myAPI`  routes here referring to  `${API_URI_DEV}/qrcode/decrypt` or you made a common mistake here?

Comment: @SandeepPatel Yes `myAPI` refers to `${API_URI_DEV}/qrcode/decrypt`. I just update the question. Thanks!